# Как оптимизировать код c проверкой len() нескольких переменных?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

Есть часть кода:

```
        if len(end_test) > 0:
            if len(marking) > 0:
                if len(start_test) > 0:
                    if len(object_trials) > 0:
                        if len(data_protocol) > 0:
                            if len(namber_protocol) > 0:
                                if len(data_application) > 0:
                                    if len(namber_application) > 0:
                                        pass
                                    else:
                                        pass
                                else:
                                    pass
                            else:
                                pass
                        else:
                            pass
                    else:
                        pass
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
```

Который проверяет длину переменно и если она не равна нулю проверяет другую переменную. Вопрос как и можно ли оптимизировать данный код??? В `else` будет писаться активация функции с выводом messageBox.

Comment: Во всех блоках `else:` будет одно и то же, или разный код?

Comment: @GrAnd да, там будет активации функции с выводом messageBox.

Comment: Так разное или абсолютно (до буквы) одно и тоже?

Comment: @GrAnd абсолютно пример: self.message() везде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно избавиться от "лесенки" просто перевернув условия:

```
if (len(end_test) <= 0 or len(marking) <= 0 or len(start_test) <= 0 or
    len(object_trials) <= 0 or len(data_protocol) <= 0 or len(namber_protocol) <= 0 or
    len(data_application) <= 0 or len(namber_application) <= 0
   ):
    self.message()
else:
    pass
```

Comment: а, почему написано len(end_test) <= 0 ? То есть равно или меньше нуля? Или я что-то путаю.

Comment: Хотя можно и не переворачивать, а написать через  `and`. Зависит от остального кода вокруг. Лично я, если проверяю на ошибки, предпочитаю сообщения вставлять в код под `if` (там часто происходит return, к примеру), а под `else` уже нормальную работу. Так нагляднее.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров Потому что `меньше или равно` это обратная операция к `больше`.

Answer (score 8):

```py
sequences = (
    end_test, marking, start_test, object_trials, data_protocol,
    namber_protocol, data_application, namber_application,
)

if all(len(x) > 0 for x in sequences):
   # все непустые
else:
   # хотя бы одна пустая
```

хотя в большинстве случаев будет достаточно

```
if all(sequences):
   # все непустые
else:
   # хотя бы одна пустая
```

потому, что пустая последовательность обычно приводится к `bool` со значением `False`, а непустая - со значением `True`

Comment: Одно замечание. Если в этих переменных содержатся большой объём immutable данных, собирание их в кортеж приведёт к лишнему расходу памяти (хоть и временному).

Comment: @GrAnd не важно, сколько данных в самих последовательностях, в кортеж попадут только ссылки на них. Т.е. в данном случае потребуется дополнительная память на 8 ссылок, это очень незначительно.